# Presenting error after an asynchronous action in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am trying to register a user using a redux form. All the synchronous validation are working but the issue comes when a user submits the form and the email is already registered. An error is returned which I am able to access as follows

```
export function registerUser(details, callback) {
return(dispatch) =>{
    dispatch(startRegisteing());
    axios.post(URL, {
        "email": details['email'],
        "name": details['username'],
        "password": details['password']
    }).then((data) =>{
        callback();
        dispatch(RegistrationSuccessfull(data))
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error.response.data.message);
        //throw new SubmissionError(error.response.data.message);
        dispatch(RegistrationFailed(error.response.data.message))
    })
}
}
```

The `RegistrationFailed` action

```
export function RegistrationFailed(error) {
return{
    type: types.REGISTRATION_ERROR,
    payload:error
}
}
```

The reducer for it just updates the state

```
switch (action.type){
    case types.REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL:
    console.log("nanana too ", action);
    return{
        ...state, isRegisteringUser:false,
        data:action.data
    };
    case types.REGISTRATION_ERROR:
    console.log("current state", state);
    return{
        ...state, error: action.payload
    }
}
```

My question is how can I be able to present this error to the User in the form

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                        <Field
                            name="username"
                            lable="Username"
                            type="text"
                            component={ this.renderField }
                        />
                        <Field
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            lable="Email"
                            component={ this.renderField }
                        />
                        {// I want to present the error here }
                        {error  && <strong>{error}</strong>}
                        <Field
                            name="password"
                            type="password"
                            lable="Password"
                            component={ this.renderField }
                        />
                        <Field
                            name="confirm_password"
                            type="password"
                            lable="Confirm Password"
                            component={ this.renderField }
                        />
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={submitting}>Register</button>
                        <Link className="btn btn-danger" to="/login">Cancel</Link>

                    </form>
```

I have tried `throw new SubmissionError(error.response.data.message);` as the react-form documentation says but its raising an error that the `Unhandled rejection SubmissionError: Submit Validation Failed`
**Note:** Am a beginner in react-redux. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing the error in the `error` field of the state in the redux store, you can subscribe to this field in your form using `mapStateToProps` and display the message if the field is not null.

```
...
import ...
...

class YourComponent extends React.Component{

       render(){
             return(
                     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                        <Field
                            name="username"
                            lable="Username"
                            type="text"
                            component={ this.renderField }
                        />
                        <Field
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            lable="Email"
                            component={ this.renderField }
                        />

                        {this.state.yourReducer.error  && <strong>{this.state.yourReducer.error}</strong>}
                        <Field
                            name="password"
                            type="password"
                            lable="Password"
                            component={ this.renderField }
                        />
                        <Field
                            name="confirm_password"
                            type="password"
                            lable="Confirm Password"
                            component={ this.renderField }
                        />
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={submitting}>Register</button>
                        <Link className="btn btn-danger" to="/login">Cancel</Link>

                    </form>
                  );
             }

}

const mapStateToProps=(state) =>{
   "yourReducer": state.yourReducer
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but since I am using redux-form, the form fields are not being rerendered once the `error` state changes. when I
`{console.log("cheki...",error)}
                            {error  && <strong>{error}</strong>}` the logs only appear before the form is submitted but once it's submitted the logs are not printed suggesting the fields are not rerendered once the state changes or Why would it be behaving like this??

Comment: Can you post the code for your component ? A http://codesandbox.io for it would be even better.

Comment: can you switch the order of the connections in your export statement?  something like `export default connect(mapStateToProps, { registerUser })(reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'registrationform'
})(RegisterForm))`

Comment: It still isn't working. I think the issues might be how redux-form manages its state

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapStateToProps to bind your store to the props inside the component, then you will be able to use this.props on your store directly and display the error.